# Persisting the values of radio buttons and date fields with the values stored in the database

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have radio buttons and date fields in my jsp form. The date fields will appear/hide based on the values of the radio button selected.I am giving the values and submitting the form , it is successfully works and stores in a database. After Submitting, when I revisited the form to update , the radio buttons are not getting populated with the database stored values.

This is the problem in my spring boot application

I want to get the value of radio button from the database and need to be populated when revisited using jstl tags.

Yes
  No

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: <input id="ssubmitYes" name="sSubmit"  type="radio" value="yes"  />Yes
  <input id="ssubmitNo" name="sSubmit" type="radio" value="no" />No

Comment: The above are two radio buttons in my form.I selected the buttons and submitted the form. When I opened the form again, they are not getting populated with the stored value.Please help me in doing this.